# Flex Builder, How do I sort this time ArrayCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder

How do I sort this time ArrayCollection? I need it to be sorted from earliest to latest.

"8:00am"
"2:00pm"
"10:00am"
"11:00am"
"12:00pm"
"7:00am"
"3:00pm"
"4:00pm"

Answer (score 1):

See this ArrayCollection sorting utility:

http://cyrilmazur.com/2010/08/sort-arraycollection-flex.html

Should be a great starting/end point

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is collection of strings. To sort it, get Array from ArrayCollection with `source` property. Look into [Array.sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort%28%29) method. You'll need to implement compare function to pass into `sort` method. The thing that left is how to tell which date is later - you can try parseDate, or break string into parts and count number of hours yourself.

Comment: I decided to go with a sort number created by the times and the am_pm themselves taking into account the 12am and 12pm conundrum. Because I have access to each separate hour/minute/ampm before they are injected into the arraycollection.